# Help with some double integral

Tags: multivariable-calculus

$$\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\int_{x}^{\pi/2}\frac{\cos y}{y} \, \operatorname{d}\!y\, \operatorname{d}\!x$$

$\iint_R2xy^2 \, \operatorname{d}\!A$ where R is the right half of the unit circle

Comment: Are you sure this is correct? Your integrand is a function of $y$ only. The integral with respect to $x$ can be replaced by a factor of $\frac{\pi}{2}$.

Comment: that should be right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That first one doesn't converge. Note that if it did, $$\begin{align}\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\cos y}y\,dy &= \int_0^{\pi/3}\frac{\cos y}y\,dy+\int_{\pi/3}^{\pi/2}\frac{\cos y}y\,dy\\ &\geq \int_0^{\pi/3}\frac{\cos y}y\,dy\\ &\geq \frac12\int_0^{\pi/3}\frac1y\,dy\\ &=\frac12\lim_{a\to 0^+}\int_a^{\pi/3}\frac1y\,dy.\end{align}$$ Check out that limit.

For the second one, note that in polar coordinates, the right half of the unit circle is $0\leq r\leq 1,-\frac\pi2\leq\theta\leq\frac\pi2.$ Use $x=r\cos\theta,y=r\sin\theta,dA=r\,dr\,d\theta$ to evaluate the second integral.

---

Since you've fixed your post, note that $$\int_0^{\pi/2}\int_x^{\pi/2}\frac{\cos y}y\,dy\,dx$$ is integrating the function $\frac{\cos y}y$ over the region bounded below by the line $y=x$ and above by the line $y=\frac\pi2,$ with $x$-values ranging from $0$ to $\pi/2$. Equivalently, though, it's bounded on the left by $x=0$ and on the right by the line $x=y$, with $y$-values ranging from $0$ to $\pi/2$. Hence, changing the order of integration gives us $$\begin{align}\int_0^{\pi/2}\int_x^{\pi/2}\frac{\cos y}y\,dy\,dx &= \int_0^{\pi/2}\int_0^y\frac{\cos y}y\,dx\,dy\\ &= \int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\cos y}y\left(\int_0^y\,dx\right)\,dy.\end{align}$$ Since $\int_0^y\,dx=y,$ then the rest is easy.

Comment: Condition of the problem was changed.

Comment: @M.Strochyk: Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

$$\iint_R2xy^2dA=\iint_{R=\{(x,y)\mid x^2+y^2=1,x\geq0\}}2xy^2dxdy=\int_0^12x\int_{-\sqrt{1-x^2}}^{\sqrt{1-x^2}}y^2dy\\=\int_0^12r\cos(\theta)\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}r^2\sin^2(\theta)rdrd\theta=\int_0^12r^4dr\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\cos(\theta)\sin^2(\theta)d\theta$$

Comment: Your final line here doesn't make sense. $r$ cannot show up outside of the integral with respect to $r$, and you have $dr$ occurring first, but the inner limits being the limits for $\theta$. It should be $\int_0^1\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} 2r^3 \cos\theta\sin^2\theta rd\theta dr$.

Comment: @GlenO: Dear friend, there is no difference in writhing inside or outside. They are independent because the area in polar coordinates is rectangular. But the form you remarked is good. I'll fix it. :-)

Comment: You know, you could write the integrals with the $d$'s first, adjacent to the integral signs.  That way, there is never confusion as to what variable goes with what integral.  But then again, you'll get dozens of questions asking if you know how to read.

Comment: @BabakS. - I'm sorry, but you're wrong. Let me put it this way - right now, the integrand of the outer integral looks like this: $$2r\cos(\theta)\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} r^2 \sin^2(\theta)rdr$$ Do you see the problem?

Comment: @amWhy: I was too Amy. Moreover, I am supposed to go to a nice Museum today and maybe I am not be here for hours. Wish you luck and I hope you have a nice and deep an shiny sleep ahead. :-)

Comment: Have a really nice visit at the Museum! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Сhange the order of integration in the first integral:
 $$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\int_{x}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\cos y}{y} \, \operatorname{d}\!y\, \operatorname{d}\!x=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\int_{0}^{y}\frac{\cos y}{y} \, \operatorname{d}\!x\, \operatorname{d}\!y=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\cos y}{y}  \int_{0}^{y}\, \operatorname{d}\!x\, \operatorname{d}\!y= \\
= \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\cos y}{y} \cdot{y}\,\operatorname{d}\!y=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}{\cos y}\,\operatorname{d}\!y=\left.\sin{y} \right|_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}=1$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\int_{x}^{\pi/2}\frac{\cos y}{y} \, \operatorname{d}\!y\, \operatorname{d}\!x = \int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{\cos y}{y}\int_{0}^{y} \, \operatorname{d}\!x\, \operatorname{d}\!y=\ldots.  $$