# How to solve this double integral? $ \int_0^{\pi/2}\int_{x}^{\pi/2} \frac{\cos{y}} y\, dy ~dx$

Tags: integration

$$ \int_0^{\pi/2}\int_{x}^{\pi/2} \frac{\cos{y}} y\, dy ~dx$$

I'm not sure how to go about integrating this. I think that I need to integrate with respect to $y$ first because the lower bound is $x$, which would be used for the integration with respect to $x$.

But, I don't know how to go about integrating the function with respect to $y$. How can this be done?

Comment: Change the limits, and integrate w.r.t. $x$ first.

Comment: Won't that just give me a constant multiplied by the function itself to integrate?

Comment: It will change your bounds and not be 'just a constant.'

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Help with some double integral](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/344119/help-with-some-double-integral)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\int\limits_0^{\pi/2}\int\limits_x^{\pi/2}\frac{\cos y}{y}dydx=\int\limits_0^{\pi/2}\int\limits_0^y\frac{\cos y}{y}dxdy=\left.\int\limits_0^{\pi/2}\cos y\,dy=\sin x\right|_0^{\pi/2}=1$$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** define $f(x):=\int_x^{\frac\pi 2}\frac{\cos y}ydy$, and integrate by parts:
$$\int_0^{\frac\pi 2}f(x)dx=\frac{\pi}2f\left(\frac{\pi}2\right)-\int_0^{\frac{\pi}2}xf'(x)dx.$$